# How to get variable changes outside of nesting in rust?

Tags: rust

Hey so I'm really new to rust and programming at large and I'm having some issues I haven't encountered before. I'm attempting to return the results of user input variables to the screen outside of nesting but I haven't seemed to have any luck.

```
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

fn main(){
    let mut modifer = 0;
    let mut ModValue=0;
    let mut ModReason = "";

    let Y = "Y";
    let y = "y";
    let N = "N";
    let n = "n";

    print!("{esc}c", esc = 27 as char);
    let mut ModYN = String::new();
    println!("Are there any modifiers (Y/N)");
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut ModYN).unwrap();
    let ModYN = ModYN.trim();

    if ModYN == y || ModYN == Y{
        ModValue = 1;
        print!("{esc}c", esc = 27 as char);
        let mut modifer:f32=0.0;
        let mut input = String::new();
    
        //I'm attempting to get the input from the user to define a modifer reason and value
        println!("Please enter the modifer: ");
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Not a valid string");
        modifer = input.trim().parse().expect("Not a valid number");

        let mut ModReason = String::new();
        println!("Whats the modifer reason: ");
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut ModReason).unwrap();
        let ModReason = ModReason.trim();
    }
    //Then print those results to the screen outside of nesting
    print!("{esc}c", esc = 27 as char);
    println!("-Modifer-");
    println!("{}",&mut modifer);
    println!("-Modifer Reason-");
    println!("{}",&mut ModReason);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
}
```

I've attempted a variety of things; from assigning it as a mutable or borrowing the variable itself to even extending the nesting past the print results. But I've hit a brick wall and could really use some help.

Comment: `let` declares a variables, you need to use `=` to assign it later. You can move `let mut ModReason = String::new()` before the `let` block and assign to it using `ModReason = ModReason.trim().to_string()`. (`to_string()` is needed because `trim()` returns `&str`, and you want an owned string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several flaws in your code, and since your question in only about one, I'll explain only about that one. This means that the code below **will not compile**. But it will get you closer to the solution.

Your problem, I think, comes from the fact that you don't know the difference between `let var = value` and `var = value`. These are very different statements: the second one assigns `value` to `var`, while the first one *creates* a new variable (shadowing a variable with the same name, if there was one), then assigns to it. It is the same as

```rust
let var;
var = value;
```

So when, in the loop, you create a new variable `ModReason`, you are not modifying the one outside the loop: you are effectively creating a new variable, just to destroy it at the end of the `if` statement (without using it). So the solution is to not create a new variable each time:

```rust
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

fn main(){
    let mut modifer = 0;
    let mut ModValue=0;
    let mut ModReason = "";

    let Y = "Y";
    let y = "y";
    let N = "N";
    let n = "n";

    print!("{esc}c", esc = 27 as char);
    let mut ModYN = String::new();
    println!("Are there any modifiers (Y/N)");
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut ModYN).unwrap();
    let ModYN = ModYN.trim();

    if ModYN == y || ModYN == Y{
        ModValue = 1;
        print!("{esc}c", esc = 27 as char);
        let mut modifer:f32=0.0;
        let mut input = String::new();
    
        //I'm attempting to get the input from the user to define a modifer reason and value
        println!("Please enter the modifer: ");
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Not a valid string");
        modifer = input.trim().parse().expect("Not a valid number");

        ModReason = String::new();
        println!("Whats the modifer reason: ");
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut ModReason).unwrap();
        ModReason = ModReason.trim();
    }
    //Then print those results to the screen outside of nesting
    print!("{esc}c", esc = 27 as char);
    println!("-Modifer-");
    println!("{}",&mut modifer);
    println!("-Modifer Reason-");
    println!("{}",&mut ModReason);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
}
```

Rust would have warned you (because, in this way, you never assign to `ModReason` outside of the loop) if you didn't print `ModReason` by passing a mutable borrow (which is absolutely useless: just go with `println!("{}", ModReason);`).

Also, it is very likely that Rust has warned you about several variables that are not used: if you read these warnings, you can understand that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! And your answer worked; I wouldn't mind you elaborating on any other issues you may see with my code as I'm really new and want to improve. I'm pretty much self-taught so there's bound to be tons of mistakes. If not; do you know anywhere that I might be able to get code evals/overall suggestions? Stack and Reddit are really my only sources of direct feedback

Comment: @Xanthus First of all, I think the compiler feedback is the tightest feedback loop you'll find. The only problem is that you may not understand right away what it means when it warns you about something. Searching directly for the output of the compiler you don't understand will lead you to posts of people having done the same thing as you, and other people explaining the issue. Besides that, when it's about errors, SO is suitable, but SO questions should only be about a single issue at a time. If you want a review of your whole code, try [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Also, about the other issues: first of all, you'll have a type error when you try to compile the code I gave you. It's pretty straightforward once you know the difference between `&str` and `String` to patch it so, either you know, and, well, go ahead, or you don't, and, well, read about it. If you have any question about that, feel free to ask. A second issue is that your variable names are not camel_cased. Furthermore, some variables are simply never used.

Comment: Also, your code almost looks like C code to me: at the beginning of your function, you "declare" variables by filling them with dummy values, and then you "assign" them. In Rust, you should instead assign then directly. Keep in mind that `if ... { ... } else { ... }` is an expression, so you could do `let mod_reason = if mod_yn == "Y" || ... { ... } else { ... }`. This would also force you to handle better the case where there are no modifiers, as currently it will just print an empty line. Maybe you could use an `Option<String>`, print the modifiers only if it is `Some(...)`.

Comment: I could go on about how to refactor your code, but I don't feel it would be very helpful to you right now. I think you'd be better off by learning how to write *correct code*, which will lead you naturally to write *well-written code*. TL;DR the best source of feedback you could imagine is the compiler warnings. If you want even more pedantic warnings (which I recommend), try clippy.